# How to create a installer/liveboot USB of a Linux OS without using any specialised tools? How does the process works?

Tags: boot, uefi

When an OS is installed on a HDD and system is booting in UEFI Mode, it requires a seperate ESP partition to store all the boot files required by UEFI boot manager like bootloader and stuff, however the system files (root filesystem) are stored on separate partition. Now coming to (Liveboot USB)/Installer for UEFI boot manager, we simply create a gpt partition table, create a fat32/vfat partition, copy the contents of iso file of OS and then its ready to boot. Question is why don't we need a separate system partition, Does UEFI boot manager not need a seperate ESP partition in this case? Where am i wrong in my observation?

Comment: UEFI only reads FAT32. Not sure it would boot from an external FAT32 flash drive without it also having boot/esp flags. Some UEFI may see external drive and if FAT32 look for boot file. Boot file name for all external devices is /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi whether Windows or Linux. But obviously bootx64.efi is a different file depending on system.

Comment: https://www.happyassassin.net/posts/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/   This article is very helpful in explaining the entire uefi booting process, just leaving it out here for someone who is in same position as me in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the whole external boot media is FAT32 which one probably wants to avoid for as much of the real system's disk space as possible; you might also find [Rod's books on UEFI](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html) useful (that's what helped me implement UEFI support in ALT Linux, for one).